# How to create trigger in SQL?

Tags: mysql

Product (PID, name, price, description)
Now create a trigger in Product relation to insert the price change information in a new relation
PRICE_CHANGE (PID, oldprice, newprice, changed-date) after the price is changed/updated in the product
relation.

Comment: What have you researched so far yourself? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple see

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER after_Product_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON Product  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.price <> NEW.price THEN
        INSERT INTO PRICE_CHANGE VALUES (NEW.PID,OLD.price, NEW.price, NOW());        
    END IF;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```